# OverlayTrigger on custom component not working

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a Popover when a custom component (a button) is hovered:

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<MyComponentProperties>  {
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        const overlay: JSX.Element = (
            <Popover id={this.uuid}>
                <Popover.Content>
                    Hello world!
                </Popover.Content>
            </Popover>
        );

        return <OverlayTrigger trigger="hover" placement="auto" delay={{show : 700, hide : 0}} overlay={overlay}>
            <MyFancyButton ... />
        </OverlayTrigger >
    }
}
```

```
class MyFancyButton extends React.PureComponent<MyFancyButtonProperties> {
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <button ...>Hover me!</button>
    }
}
```

The Popover doesn't show. However, it works if I change the return of the `render` function of `MyComponent` to:

```
return <OverlayTrigger trigger="hover" placement="auto" delay={{show : 700, hide : 0}} overlay={overlay}>
    <button>Hover me!</button>
</OverlayTrigger >
```

I checked https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlay-trigger and it says:

> Note that triggering components **must be able to accept a ref** since  will attempt to add one. You can use forwardRef() for function components.

I'm not sure how to do this. I tried adding a `ref` property in `MyFancyButtonProperties` and forwarding it to `button`, but it doesn't work:

```
class MyFancyButton extends React.PureComponent<MyFancyButtonProperties> {
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <button ref={this.props.ref} ...>Hover me!</button>
    }
}
```

My versions:

- React 16.8.6
- React bootstrap 1.0.0-beta.14

Comment: I asked a somewhat similar question to see why forwardRef does not seem to work correctly with bootstrap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875068/react-forwardref-does-not-seem-to-work-with-bootstrap-overlay

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I finally found a solution here: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2208#issuecomment-301737531

I wrapped the component, which should get a tooltip, with a `<span>` in the `render` function of `MyComponent` to

```
return <OverlayTrigger trigger="hover" placement="auto" delay={{show : 700, hide : 0}} overlay={overlay}>
    <span><MyFancyButton ... /></span>
</OverlayTrigger >
```

and now it works.

Comment: This breaks placement location in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Your custom component needs to pass the event handler props through.

```
const FancyButton = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <Button {...props}>
    {children}
  </Button>
);
```

Source: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2208

Comment: This maintains control over the DOM without having to add an extra span.

Comment: IMHO, this is the best solution.