# React forwardRef does not seem to work with bootstrap Overlay

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-forwardref

According to [React-Bootstrap Overlays docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/), the target of the overlay should be `the element the overlay is positioned in relation to` which works beautifully if the target is inline. such as the **Example 1** below.

If however the referenced dom item is contained inside of another component as illustrated with **Example 2** then the reference is not setup correctly and the popover does not get positioned correctly.

I was not forwarding the ref at first, and believed that to be my problem, but even after fixing that according to the [React.forwardRef docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref), the ref is still not working correctly.

*Possible Solution:* I could put my target incline instead of another component but that removes the purpose of being able to use components in React.

I am probably missing a small step somewhere in this setup, I just don't know where.

I did find an alternative working solution as I was writing this out and looking for duplicates. As seen in [Simon Arsenault's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60422359/1707323) by wrapping the component in a dom element, I could use that dom element as the ref as seen in **Example 3**

I would still like to know why the forwardRef does not seem to work though.

**Example 1:** Working

```js
...
export default (props) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
  const target = useRef(null)
  ...
  return (
    <div>
      <p ref={target} >Click Me</p>
      <Overlay show={show} target={target.current} >
        <Popover id='123'>
          ...
        </Popover>
      </Overlay>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Example 2:** Not Working

```js
...
export default (props) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
  const target = useRef(null)
  ...
  return (
    <div>
      <LinkIcon ref={target} />
      <Overlay show={show} target={target.current} >
        <Popover id='123'>
          ...
        </Popover>
      </Overlay>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
...
const LinkIcon = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  ...
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      ...
    </div>
  )
})
```

**Example 3:** Working

```js
...
export default (props) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
  const target = useRef(null)
  ...
  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={target}><LinkIcon /></div>
      <Overlay show={show} target={target.current} >
        <Popover id='123'>
          ...
        </Popover>
      </Overlay>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
...
const LinkIcon = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  ...
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      ...
    </div>
  )
})
```

*P.S.*: Yes, I know this is not a fully working example because I do not use Overlay's `show` property, but that is working correctly and left out of this code snippet for brevity.

Comment: Don't forget to add your passthrough `createRef()` via `<LinkIcon ref={ref}` per (the docs)[https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html]